# New to Bootstrap - having some mobile styling issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap, and I have some issues with my mobile view:

Link: http://bit.ly/1yYmgvI

Now obviously the mobile view is a mess. I'll go through a couple issues I'm having:

- The navigation drop down works, but the background is non-existent when clicked.
- How do I move the "we design IOS apps" up? I tried the "pull" class but that actually pulled it horizontally, not upwards.
- How do I adjust the height of different rows for mobile view? As you can tell, the services height (the white background) needs to be extended much longer, but it's quite short in mobile.

I'm pretty new to this so if you guys could help me out that'd be so appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to give the background of the navigation dropdown a `background-color`, like this:

```
.navHeaderCollapse {
    background-color: #222;
}
```

If you want to minimize the padding, so that you can move the "we design IOS apps" up, you can use a media query at your desired change browser width, which changes the padding. Use it like this:

```
@media (max-width: 765px) {
    .xlg-buffer {
        padding-top: 35px;
    }
}
```

The same works for adjusting the heights of the different rows in "mobile view". Just use an according `media-query` to change the heights. For example like this:

```
@media (max-width: 765px) {
    .row-services {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

All given values are just examples, you need to adapt them to your needs. Use the `browser inspector` to find out which selectors you need to target and which properties you need to change.